# Pan to markers using `For` loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet

I have couple of markers (Leaflet) in the array like

```
var marker1 = L.marker(...);
var marker2 = L.marker(...);
...
```

Added in array as

```
var markerArray = [];
markerArray.push(marker1);
markerArray.push(marker2);
...
```

And now I need to use a `For` loop to create a function that pans to the marker that I click. I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
    markerArray[i].on("click", function() {
        mymap.panTo(markerArray[i].getLatLng());    
    })
};
```

Any help?

Comment: Try replace function with: function(e) {mymap.panTo(e.latlng;}

Answer (score 1):

What you do is attaching event handlers to markers (see [doc](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#evented)).

In your event handler, the marker is the target of the event (e.target).

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
    markerArray[i].on("click", function(e) {
        mymap.panTo(e.target.getLatLng());    
    })
};
```

You can write it another way to realize the i variable has no meaning in the event handler:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
    markerArray[i].on("click", markerClicked);              
};

function markerClicked(e) {
    mymap.panTo(e.target.getLatLng()); 
}
```